# jquery overlay doesn't fire on localhost

Tags: jquery, localhost

I'm trying to get a local testing environment sorted out and have successfully set up xampp to serve php pages. This is the first time I've done this so it's very possible I'm making newbie errors!

However, I'm aware that javascript is clientside so the fact the jquery is being served by localhost shouldn't make any difference?

I have a page with a jquery overlay and which works perfectly online - i.e., served by remote server. However, when I load the page locally served via xampp, firebug show me the following error:

```
$("#modifile_link[rel]").overlay is not a function
[Break On This Error] onBeforeLoad: function() {
```

Here's the jquery call...

```
$(function() {
    // Setup a basic iframe for use inside overlays.
    var theframe = $('<iframe class="iframe_style" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>');

    // Overlay
    $("#modifile_link[rel]").overlay({effect: 'apple',
        mask: {
            color: '#000000',
            loadSpeed: 1000,
            opacity: 0.6
        },
        closeOnClick: false,
        onBeforeLoad: function() {
            // grab wrapper element inside content
            var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
            //Get the URL from the trigger
            var link = this.getTrigger().attr("href");
            // load the page specified in the trigger
            $(theframe).attr({ src: link });
            //Write the iframe into the wrap
            wrap.html(theframe);
        }
    });
});
```

which is bound to this link...

```
<div id="modifile_link" href="scripts/modifile/index.php" rel="#overlay_1"></div>
```

and here's the html for the overlay...

```
<div class="overlay_1" id="overlay_1">
    <div class="overlay_content">
        <div class="contentWrap"></div>
    </div><!-- end overlay content -->
</div><!--end overlays html-->
```

SO, it's seems strange that in firebug the jquery file is being loaded but the onBeforeLoad: function() is not being accepted. There's no ajax going on so I thought to rule out a cross domain security restriction? I don't know.

Any pointers would be great.

Thanks.

Scott

Comment: Hi scottie. I believe you are using jquery Tools, so I would recommend be sure you are loading the js file that contains the overlay function.  I'm saying that maybe on your server that file exists, but not on localhost...

Comment: Thanks Nobita - i'll go try it now then report back... :)

Comment: hmmm - going backwards! Just downloaded a new jquery tools file from http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html, including the overlay plugin, with apple effect. Now forebug is giving me the following... jQuery is not defined
[Break On This Error] (function(a){a.tools=a.tools||{version...handle.call(this,b,b.delta)}})(jQuery)

$ is not defined
[Break On This Error] $(function() {

Comment: it looks like your jQuery file is not getting loaded locally. Can you show the code you are using to load it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your files exist on the local server and that the paths are correct. Right click the page from your browser, "view page source", and click on the javascript links to see if they open or server returns 404 not found.

If you can't access the javascript files from the browser, first check if they are even present in the local folder structure, but my guess is that your url's are wrong. Pay attention to absolute/relative paths. Try including your javascript files with a relative url 
(without a `/` in the beginning)

Comment: Thanks to you both for the help - problem now resolved! It seems that there was something wrong with jquery library file I was using so after downloading a new one and then making sure all the file paths were correct (good idea!!) things started working. Cheers guys! Scott

Comment: Also... couldn't put this in 'answer your question' as I had to re-sign up today therefore I'm technically a new user today and answering ain't allowed in the first 24 hours. Didn't fully understand why I had to re-sign up but seemed to have something to do with openID being implemented??? cheers S